# Tengo un problema al activar una clase para remplazar otra desde un metodo click, No funciona

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, eventos

estoy trabajando con angular y tengo un menú hamburguesa donde estoy tratando de que me expanda el menu lateral y se cierre cada vez que doy click en el boton pero no me funciona, para ello tengo lo siguiente:

```
    <header>
        <div id="sidemenu" class="menu-collapsed">
          <!-- HEADER -->
            <div class="header">
              <div class="title"><span>Administrador</span></div>
              <!--Boton hamburguesa:-->
//Este es el boton que llevaria el evento click para activar el efecto:
              <div class="menu-btn" (click)="menuExpanded()">
                  <!--Estos 3 divs me ayudaran a crear el icono de la hamburguesa:-->
                  <div class="btn-hamburguer"></div>
                  <div class="btn-hamburguer"></div>
                  <div class="btn-hamburguer"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- PROFILE -->
            <div class="profile">
                <div class="photo"><img src="../../../assets/images/perfil mym.jpg"></div>
                <div class="name"><span>Javier Mejía</span></div>
            </div>
            <!-- ITEMS MENU -->
            <div class="menu-items">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="item-text">
                      <div class="icon"><img src="../../../assets//images/home-icon.png"></div>
                      <div class="title"><a>Home</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-text">
                      <div class="icon"><img src="../../../assets//images/employee-icon.png"></div>
                      <div class="title"><a>Empleados</a></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-text">
                      <div class="icon"><img src="../../../assets//images/dashboard-icon.png"></div>
                      <div class="title"><a>Dashboard</a></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

Este es el estilo del sidemenu cuando esta expandido:

```
#sidemenu{
  background-color: var(--sidebar-primary-color);
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

Notese que el contenedor donde lleva la clase `"sidemenu"` existe otra clase que se llama `menu-collapsed,` es esta la clase que voy a usar para hacer este efecto. Entonces en orden tengo el siguiente codigo:
la siguiente es la clase que reemplazaria la clase `menu-collapsed` cuando le demos click al boton, lo que hace es que dejará el menu expandido:

```
.menu-expanded{
  width: 300px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5); //Para saber que el menu sidebar esta expandido
}
.menu-expanded .header .title{
  display: inline-block;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
  margin-right: -5px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.menu-expanded .header .title span{
  width: calc( 300px - 50px - 5px);//La medida para el span es le ancho del sidebar- los 50px de los iconos de cada menu - 5px
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

//Cuando le menu sidebar este expandido:
.menu-expanded .profile .photo{
  width: 200px;
}
.menu-expanded .profile .name{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Ahora, despues de ese codigo tengo el siguiente estilo en donde con la clase menu-collapsed activa el sidemenu se va a medio esconder, porque se veeria solo los iconos del menu por ello el ancho del 50px:

```
.menu-collapsed{
  width: 50px
}
.menu-collapsed .header .title{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.menu-collapsed .profile .name{
  display: none;
}
.menu-collapsed .item{
  width: 100%;
}
```

Este es el codigo que tengo en el componente typeScript:

```
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit {
  menu= document.getElementById('sidemenu')
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
```

Este es el metodo que accionará el evento click:

```
menuExpanded(){
    this.menu?.classList.toggle('menu-expanded');
    this.menu?.classList.toggle('menu-collapsed');
    document.querySelector('body')?.classList.toggle('body-expanded')
  }
```

Esté sería el boton hamburguesa con el evento click:

```
<div class="menu-btn" (click)="menuExpanded()">
              <!--Estos 3 divs me ayudaran a crear el icono de la hamburguesa:-->
              <div class="btn-hamburguer"></div>
              <div class="btn-hamburguer"></div>
              <div class="btn-hamburguer"></div>
          </div>
```

No entiendo porque al dar click en el boton, el sidemenu no me cambia de una clase a otra para expandir y ocultar el menu, si algun compañero me puede ayudar le agredeceria muchisimo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trabajando con Angular generalmente no es buena idea acceder al DOM directamente, hay otras formas más sencillas de hacer lo que quieres:

Primero, puedes usar `ngClass` para elegir la clase asignada a un elemento:

```
<div id="sidemenu" [ngClass]="{'menu-expanded': isMenuExpanded, 'menu-collapsed': !isMenuExpanded }">
```

De este modo tu lógica quedaría así de sencilla:

```
//propiedad de tu componente
isMenuExpanded : boolean = false;

toggleMenuExpanded(){
   this.isMenuExpanded = !this.isMenuExpanded;
}
```

Puedes mirar esta otra pregunta/respuesta para ver más opciones: [¿Cómo establecer multiples operadores ternarios en ngClass?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/262064/como-establecer-multiples-operadores-ternarios-en-ngclass)

Comment: Genial brother me sirvio, muchas gracias